# UIScrollView Scrolls Too Much

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a UIScrollView with several large UIViews (larger than the visible area of the scroll view). I have the following line:

```
[[self scrollView] setContentSize:CGSizeMake([self scrollView].bounds.size.width, [ListItemView instanceHeight] * MAX_NUMBER_ITEMS)];
```

ListItemView is a custom view and instanceHeight is a static height that they all have (ie. the second argument should be the total height of all contents, which works fine). The problem is that, even though I've made the content size (I believe) equal to the actual size of the scroll view, it still horizontally scrolls (simulated on all iPhone sizes).

A horizontal scrollbar continues to appear until I put the content size to 250. I found this through trial and error (at 251 a horizontal scrollbar appears, at 250 it doesn't). Why is this? I'd expect the scrollbar to go away once the contentSize is less than the scrollBar's actual size (which is the width of the screen, 320).

Comment: Did you check the size of the scroll view at the time this line of code is called?

Comment: Yes. `NSLog(@"%f", self.scrollView.contentSize.width);
NSLog(@"%f", self.scrollView.bounds.size.width);` both show 320.

Answer (score 0):

The trick when using autolayout is that you never set the size of anything explicitly; if your constraints are set up consistently throughout your view hierarchy, everything will size itself automatically (including the content of the scrollView). If there's no way to specify the size of a view in advance, you should override intrinsicContentSize in a custom view subclass and return the size.

In your case, create a custom view which holds all your ListItemViews. In that custom class return the total height of the ListItemViews in intrinsicContentSize -- you shouldn't need to set the content size in the scrollView at all.

Comment: In other words, guess what was in the minds of XCode's creators, or prepare to suffer endless pain.